# Hide one specific woocoomerce product

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I would like to hide one specific product for all not logged in users. Suppose `$post` is that post. I used the hooks:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'WC_Query::remove_product_query' ) ;
```

and

```
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'WC_Query::pre_get_posts' );
```

but none of them seem to be working.

```
 global $post;
    if( get_post_type() == "product" )
    {
       if(is_user_logged_in()){
          return;
       }

        add_action( 'wp', 'WC_Query::remove_product_query' ) ;
        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'WC_Query::pre_get_posts' );
        $post->post_content = 'Hidden';

        return;
    }
```

Comment: you can use **private** status instead of **public**, incase you dont have any other requirements

Comment: @PiyushRawat No i have other requirements. thank you..

Comment: This code works on my localhost. Here it is : https://pastebin.com/FpZ5Ys4w

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested and works fine on a fresh WP and WooCommerce installation.

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
  function exclude_product_from_users($q){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $prodcuts_ids = array(648);
    $q->set( 'post__not_in', $prodcuts_ids );
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'exclude_product_from_users' );
  function return_from_product_page(){
    global $post;
    $prodcuts_ids = array(648);
    if(in_array( $post->ID , $prodcuts_ids)){
        wp_redirect(home_url('/'));
        exit();
    }
  }
  add_action('wp', 'return_from_product_page');
}
```